# When building a Java GraphQL API , how can I avoid Over-Fetching from the DB (i.e. fetching only for the fields specified in the query)?

Tags: api, graphql, graphql-java

In most example I saw there I need to implement a fletcher for each type I.e. having one generic query for each type.
As one of the promises of GraohQL is reducing load on the server, I wonder how can I customize the query to the DB in a way it will fetch only the fields the user specify in the GraphQL query.

I know I can fetch all possible fields, but this looks to me like missing the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this specific java implementation but it will be similar to other solutions.

You have to use additional, contextual informations available to optimize DB queries. According to [docs](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v10/data-fetching/) you're probably looking for `DataFetchingEnvironment`